# zxing embedded - setCaptureActivity() causes that the activity does not appear

Tags: android, orientation, zxing

I tried to change zxing embedded scanner orientation from landscape to portrait.

I found an example how to do it in [ZE readme on github](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/README.md#changing-the-orientation). But the line

```
integrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivityAnyOrientation.class);
```

causes that the Activity is not even displayed. Without the line it works great except the portrait orientation. This code works with version 3 and higher and I use version 3.0.2.

Does anybody have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the orientation

To change the orientation, specify the orientation in your AndroidManifest.xml and let the ManifestMerger to update the Activity's definition.

Sample:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        tools:replace="screenOrientation" />

IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
integrator.initiateScan();
```